# Not able to load forecast package

Tags: r

> library(forecast)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘lifecycle’ 0.1.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.2.0 is required
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘forecast’ was built under R version 3.6.3

I updated RStudio & all packages.

Comment: have you installed it, try installing again `install.packages('forecast')`

Comment: Please update the version of R first and then use the command `install.packages('forecast', dependencies=T)` to install the packages and it's dependencies and retry loading using `library(forecast)`.